# Removing single word strings from a Dataframe and moving them to a csv

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I'm trying to remove single word strings from a dataframe (`ou`) and move it to another dataframe (`removedSet` and `allowedSet`), and then to a csv (`names.csv` and `removed.csv`). I am able to filter out specific strings, but I am having trouble removing single words from the dataframe I just made `allowedSet`.

So I need to use the two dataframes I just made and check them for the single word strings. I want to append the single words to the dataframe with removed strings `removedSet` and remove the single words from the other dataframe with only full names `allowedSet`.

This is my desired output `COMPnames.csv`:

```
COMP:Jenny Pepper:
COMP:Harry Perlinkle
```

`COMPremoved.csv`

```
COMP:LINK:
COMP:Printer90
COMP:faxeast test
```

But my `COMPnames.csv` file has:

```
COMP:Jenny Pepper:
```

and `COMPremoved.csv`

```
COMP:Harry Perlinkle
COMP:LINK:
COMP:Printer90
COMP:faxeast test
```

Then do the same for NEWS department, etc.

The code below shows what I have attempted so far.

This is a smaller scale example of my code that you can run:

```
import pandas as pd

ou = {'OU':  ['COMP:Jenny Pepper:', 'COMP:Harry Perlinkle', 'COMP:LINK:', 'NEWS:Peter Parker:', 'NEWS:PARK:', 'NEWS:Clark Kent:', 'NEWS:Store Merch', 'COMP:Printer90', 'NEWS:store123', 'COMP:faxeast test']}

df = pd.DataFrame(ou)

#my ou list
oulist = pd.DataFrame({'OU':['COMP', 'NEWS']})

#the strings I want to remove
removeStr = ['printer', 'store', 'fax', 'link', 'park']

for dept in oulist ['OU']:
        #I want only the rows that contains strings in the OU column
        df_dept = df[df['OU'].str.startswith(f'{dept}:')]
        
        #put all of them in one csv file
        df_dept['OU'].to_csv(f'{dept}all.csv', index=False, header=False)
        
        #these two lines look in the removeStr list and make sure to check between the ':' so it doesn't grab the department name.         
        removedStr = [any(x in row[row.find(':')+1:].lower() for x in removeStr ) for row in df_dept['OU']]
        allowedStr = [all(not x in row[row.find(':')+1:].lower() for x in removeStr ) for row in df_dept['OU']]
        
        #remake the dataframe now
        removedSet = df_dept[removedStr]
        csvRemove = f'{dept}removed.csv'
        
        allowedSet = df_dept[allowedStr ]
        csvAllowed = f'{dept}names.csv'

        #move both of them to csv
        removedSet.to_csv(csvRemove, sep=',', encoding='utf-8', index=False,  mode='a', header=False)
        allowedSet.to_csv(csvAllowed , sep=',', encoding='utf-8', index=False, mode='a', header=False)
```

Below shows one of my attempts. I thought manually removing the single word strings through a simple `str.split()`, and then move them to new dataframes, `df1` and `df2`. But this also didn't wors.

```
m=removedSet['OU'].str.split('^[\w]+\:|\s').str.len()==2
m=list(m) #as this is how it's outputted for removedStr and allowedStr
df1=removedSet[m]
df2=allowedSet[~m]

#move both of them to csv
df1.to_csv(csvRemove, sep=',', encoding='utf-8', index=False,  mode='a', header=False)
df2.to_csv(csvAllowed , sep=',', encoding='utf-8', index=False, mode='a', header=False)
```

I got this error:

```
df2=allowedSet[~m]
TypeError: bad operand type for unary ~: 'list'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, use a regex with word boundaries and `groupby` to save your files:

```
import re
regex = '|'.join(re.escape(w) for w in removeStr)
# 'printer|store|fax|link|park'

group1 = df['OU'].str.extract('([^:]+)', expand=False)
group2 = (df['OU'].str.contains(fr'\b({regex})\d*\b', case=False)
                  .map({True: 'removed',
                        False: 'names'}))
for (g1, g2), g in df.groupby([group1, group2]):
    filename = f'{g1}_{g2}.csv'
    print(f'saving "{filename}"')
    print(g)
    #g.to_csv(filename) # uncomment to save
```

output:

```
saving "COMP_names.csv"
                     OU
0    COMP:Jenny Pepper:
1  COMP:Harry Perlinkle
9     COMP:faxeast test
saving "COMP_removed.csv"
               OU
2      COMP:LINK:
7  COMP:Printer90
saving "NEWS_names.csv"
                   OU
3  NEWS:Peter Parker:
5    NEWS:Clark Kent:
saving "NEWS_removed.csv"
                 OU
4        NEWS:PARK:
6  NEWS:Store Merch
8     NEWS:store123
```

*NB. the produced regex `'\\b(printer|store|fax|link|park)\\d*\\b'` matches the blacklisted words as whole words, optionally allowing digits at the end.*

Comment: This seems really good. However I need to have a separate file for each department `NEWS` and `COMP`. So `NEWSnames` and `NEWSremoved`, should only contain rows that start with department  `NEWS:` and `COMPnames` and `COMPremoved` should only have rows that start with department `COMP:`

Comment: @noobCoder easy enough, see update ;)

Comment: Thank you @mozway :) Regex is very a powerful tool.